# Parsing JSON by jqGrid : Difference between {} and []

Tags: json, jqgrid

I have implemented jqgrid as.,

```
$(function () {
    $("#accountHeadList").jqGrid({
        //url: '../../jqGridHandler1.ashx',
        url: '/Personalize/GetAccountHeads',
        datatype: 'json',
        width  : 400,
        height : 300, 
        colNames: ['name', 'value'],
        colModel: [
                { name: 'name', width: 100, sortable: true },
                { name: 'value', width: 100, sortable: true },
        ],
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        pager: '#gridPager',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: 'asc',
        multiselect: true,
        caption: 'Account Heads',         
    });

    $("#accountHeadList").jqGrid('navGrid', '#gridPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false });
});
```

When I return a JSON as.,

```
{"rows":[{"id":0,"cell":["Accounts Receivable",""]},{"id":1,"cell":["Acd",""]},{"id":2,"cell":["Bank Accounts",""]},{"id":3,"cell":["Cash On Hand",""]},{"id":4,"cell":["Income Tax Payable",""]},{"id":5,"cell":["Interest Payable",""]},{"id":6,"cell":["Investment Premium Payable",""]},{"id":7,"cell":["Prepaid Expenses",""]},{"id":8,"cell":["Salary \u0026 Wage Payable",""]},{"id":9,"cell":["Salary Receivable",""]},{"id":10,"cell":["Short Term Borrowing",""]}],"page":1,"total":1,"records":10}
```

It is parsing well And I am getting data in the grid. Where as., If I pass the data as below., It fails to load data, simply empty tabular column appears in the Grid,(but with a same no of rows).

```
{"rows":[{"id":0,"cell":{"name":"Accounts Receivable","value":null}},{"id":1,"cell":{"name":"Acd","value":null}},{"id":2,"cell":{"name":"Bank Accounts","value":null}},{"id":3,"cell":{"name":"Cash On Hand","value":null}},{"id":4,"cell":{"name":"Income Tax Payable","value":null}},{"id":5,"cell":{"name":"Interest Payable","value":null}},{"id":6,"cell":{"name":"Investment Premium Payable","value":null}},{"id":7,"cell":{"name":"Prepaid Expenses","value":null}},{"id":8,"cell":{"name":"Salary \u0026 Wage Payable","value":null}},{"id":9,"cell":{"name":"Salary Receivable","value":null}},{"id":10,"cell":{"name":"Short Term Borrowing","value":null}}],"page":1,"total":1,"records":10}
```

I could see the difference of `{}` and `[]` in the `cell`, which may be the source of fault. But Why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server should either returns the data in the default format in which jqGrid expect the data or you should inform jqGrid about the format of your data using [jsonReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data).

In [the feature request](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/autodetection-of-input-json-format/#p28404) and in [the pull request](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/439) are already part of jqGrid. So if you use current version of jqGrid then many (but not all) *wrong* formatted input data could be still read by jqGrid. In any way it's important to know *which version of jqGrid you use*.

If you prefer to use object form of data in JSON response from the server then the server should return `rows` part of the answer in the form

```
"rows":[
    {"id":0,"name":"Accounts Receivable","value":null},
    {"id":1,"name":"Acd","value":null},
    {"id":2,"name":"Bank Accounts","value":null},
    ...
 ]
```

(`"cell"` property should be **removed**). You will have to add `jsonReader: {repeatitems: false}` additionally if you use old version of jqGrid which not support autodetection of JSON input data.

Comment: I have `public struct JQGridResults{public int currentPage { get; set; } public int totalNoOfPages { get; set; } public int totalNoOfRecords { get; set; }  public JQGridRow[] rows;}public struct JQGridRow  {   public long id { get; set; }public string name { get; set; } public string value { get; set; }}` which I will use in JQGrid. But to improve resuablity (because different classes will have different no of data members)., **can I use** `public struct JQGridRow{public long id { get; set; }public string[] cells { get; set; }}`. Because in your answer you said "cell" should be removed!!

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT: You don't need define any struct of class which you share. C# allows you to use *anonymous* classes: `return Json(new {page = ..., rows = (from item in acHeadEntries select new[] {...}).ToList()}`. You can use `select new {id = item.id, ...} ` in the same way.

Comment: This way?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087214/i-want-a-jqgrid-class-that-can-return-json-by-mvc#13088378., But you said using `cells` is not advisable. But they are using that.

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT: Sorry, but way I wrote is another. I wrote that the items of `rows` should either `{"id":0,"cell":["Accounts Receivable",""]}` or `{"id":0,"name":"Accounts Receivable","value":null}` but not a **mix from both**: `{"id":0,"cell":{"name":"Accounts Receivable","value":null}}` which you currently use.

Comment: it is not 'they'. Actually you are using that :) Its your answer. And you missed `new` keyword near select in the above answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087214/i-want-a-jqgrid-class-that-can-return-json-by-mvc#13088378

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT: Thanks! I included missing `new` in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13088378/315935). I wrote the code of the answer without testing it. The answer should generate the items `{"id":...,"cell":[...]}` like in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935) too.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31487/discussion-between-eager-student-and-oleg)